# How to create a new column with the table name as value - SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

first of all I am new to using SQL.
I already looked on the internet and found that I could insert a new column into a tab by using the `ALTER TABLE` function. Unfortunately, I don't think this is what I'm looking for since I do not want to modify the already existing table. What I'm looking for is really simple but I don't know how to do it in SQL since I mostly use R.

**example :**

table name = `dataset1`

the current data :

```
 ID     NAME SALARY
  1     John 100000
  2     Mike  80000
  3 Rachelle  90000
```

what I would like to have as my new output :

```
 ID     NAME SALARY FROMDATA
  1     John 100000 dataset1
  2     Mike  80000 dataset1
  3 Rachelle  90000 dataset1
```

I know this is ridiculously easy but I don't want to modify the data on the server I just want to make a copy of it with a column containing the dataset name that I will save after. It can even be as simple as simply creating a column with me writting manually the name of the dataset. I know it would take me 0.01 sec with R, I feel dumb but I know nothing of SQL and I have to use it today.

Thanks and sorry for bothering you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a constant field:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SALARY, 'dataset1' AS FROMDATA
FROM dataset1;
```

This trick is more useful, and more commonly seen, when you want to take a union of two or more tables but select a column which keeps track of the table source.  For example:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SALARY, 'dataset1' AS FROMDATA FROM dataset1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, NAME, SALARY, 'dataset2' FROM dataset2   -- assuming this table exists
ORDER BY FROMDATA;
```

Comment: YES! thats exactly it and I'm also using union between 3 data sets. You're awesome, gonna accept this as the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

If you are extracting data with a `select` you can easily add your column without actually changing the structure of your table. E.g. `select *, 'dataset1' as FROMDATA from dataset1;`. Another way is creating a `view` defined as a select of your dataset1 plus the static column you want to add

Comment: Thanks, it's like Tim answered tho!